# Sound over SSH Connection in MobaXTerm

Tags: ssh

I am trying to forward a .wav sound over a ssh connection from a linux server to a local windows laptop. I ssh through MobaXTerm and X11 forwarding is on.

The goal is to output the sound from a program running on the linux box on my local speaker. For now, playing the sound directly would be sufficient.

$ paplay sound.wav does not produce any errors.

Pulse is configured, with paprefs, to find local speakers... but it doesn't.

The wav file plays fine on a local machine by mounting the directory, then playing with a windows-native player.

Is there an add on to MobaXTerm to support audio forwarding? How do I capture the forwarded sound on my Windows machine to fix what I perceive is currently a working, but not fully executed, solution?

Answer (score 4):

SSH itself doesn't have a facility for graphics or sound forwarding. The X11 protocol is network-ready¹, which allows GUI applications to be very easily forwarded over the network: all SSH has to do is to forward the network connection. The side where applications display has to have an X11 server; in addition to being an SSH client, MobaXterm includes both a terminal emulator and an X11 server.

Sound doesn't work that way, but you can make it work that way by using a sound server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_server). This means instructing the sound-producing application to use a network protocol, instructing SSH to forward the network connection, and having an application that plays sounds as received through a network connection on the client side. MobaXterm doesn't include the sound playing part, and Windows itself doesn't either (of course not) so you'll need to install one.

`paplay` talks to the [PulseAudio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PulseAudio) sound server, and you can forward that connection through SSH. On the remote machine, run

```
pacmd load-module module-native-protocol-tcp
```

(it may already have been enabled system-wide). You can also do this through paprefs. You should now have a file called `~/.pulse-cookie` or `~/.config/pulse/cookie` depending on your distribution. Copy that file to the Windows machine.

With the SSH connection, forward a port to port 4713 on the server, say 4714. (You can pick 4713 on both sides; on the server side it has to be the port where PulseAudio is listening and that's 4713 by default.) (With the OpenSSH command line, you'd do `ssh -L 4714:localhost:4713`).

On Windows, install [the PulseAudio port](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Ports/Windows/Support/). I don't know how they work as I've never used them; you'll need to point them to the cookie file and to the forwarded connection (port 4714).

See also [the official instructions](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Network/) (not all that helpful) and [grawity's post on Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/231920/forwarding-audio-like-x-in-ssh/311830#311830) which also explains how to transmit the PulseAudio connection without using SSH (this means less latency but is insecure and may be blocked by a firewall).

¹  <sub>By which I mean, it uses a protocol that is a network communication protocol in the first place.</sub>